# PHP - Convert mm/yyyy to mysql Date Format

Tags: php, date

So far I'm doing this to convert dates

`$date = '01/1990';`
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date . '/01')));`

But I get back a boolean false; Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$data` with `$date`:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-d-m', strtotime('01/' . str_replace('-', '/', $date)))));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'01/'.$date`? Otherwise its `01/1990/01`.

Answer (score 1):

Your str_replace is searching for `-` and replacing with `/`.

Here is a simplified solution that opts to not concatenate the day onto the date string.

```
$date = '01/1990';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
$date = date('Y-m-1', strtotime($date));
```

If you do want to concatenate your day onto the date string format as `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
$date = '01/1990';
$date = '01/' . $date;
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` accepts `dd-mm-yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` (and some other formats like `yyyy-mm-dd`). The **only** way to differentiate between `dd-mm-yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` is the separator.

Since you start with a string that appears to be in `mm/yyyy` format, the easiest solution would be to convert it to dd-mm-yyyy:

```
$date = '01/1990';
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('01-'.str_replace('/', '-', $date)));
```

And you also might want to check the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: `str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury You are right, I should have spotted that one. Fixed.